# OpenLayers Clustering Adds Features to Selected Features Array on Zoom

Tags: gis, openlayers

This is my first posted question despite using StackExchange for a few years now. I've been stuck for quite some time trying to figure out this issue with OpenLayers. The problem is as follows:

I have a bunch of features plotted on a map and am able to select features in various ways (e.g. drawing a box around them, clicking on individual features, entering a zip code that selects all features within that zip code, etc.). This all works fine. The issue is that I have a clustering strategy on the features layer and when I zoom out, currently selected features get clustered together with unselected features and those unselected features will become selected when I zoom back in. What I'm trying to accomplish is to NOT have the previously unselected features become selected after clustering.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour (keeping selection of subfeatures after zooming in with selected cluster) is buried quite deep inside of Strategy.Cluster code. One solution would be to get deep into the code of Strategy.Cluster and making it remember *really* selected features and select only those on zoom in (actually - on reclustering, or calling Strategy.Cluster.cluster()). Second would be to track the selected features outside of openlayers by subscribing to event featureselected and reselecting features on zoomend.

Comment: My inclination before posting this question was to just track the selected features outside of OpenLayers and reselecting them after the zoom event. Mrówa's suggestion confirmed my instincts. Thanks.